# How to find out which application consume the most space on hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

My hadoop cluster shows it has less than 20% disk space left. I am using this command to see disk space

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

However, i don't know which directory/files that takes up the most space. Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following command.

hdfs dfs -du /

It displays sizes of files and directories contained in the given directory or the length of a file in case its just a file.

Comment: i add -h to give a more user friendly print